# How would I make this script more efficient?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, gnome3

I am writing a script that will systematically install Numix theme using gnome-tweak-tool.

I want to make sure that I don't reinstall items if they are already installed, so I used `which [name of item] > /dev/null`.

Here is my current script:

```
function installNumix() {
    echo "Checking if Numix is installed ..."
    if ! which gnome-tweak-tool > /dev/null; then
        if ! which numix-gtk-theme > /dev/null; then
            if ! which numix-icon-theme-circle > /dev/null; then
                echo "Installing Numix ..."
                sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
                sudo apt-get update
                sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme-circle -y
                sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool -y
                echo "Configuring Numix:"
                echo "===================================================================="
                echo "Please use the 'tweak-tool' to change your theme to 'Numix'."
                echo "[GTK+]: Numix."
                echo "[icons]: Numix-Circle."
                echo "===================================================================="
                gnome-tweak-tool
                echo "Numix has been manually configured."
                source ~/.profile
                changeBackground backgrounds/background.png
                changeProfilePicture $(whoami) profile_pictures/profile_picture.png
                echo "The Numix has been installed."
                sleep 5
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Numix has already been installed."
        sleep 5
    fi
}
```

My `.profile` file:

```
#Change desktop background f(x)
#Ex. changeBackground  /path/to/image.png
function changeBackground() {
    FILE="file://$(readlink -f "$1")"
    fileName="${FILE##*/}" # baseName + fileExtension

    echo "Changing desktop background to: '$fileName' ..."
    dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri" "'$FILE'"
    echo "Desktop background has been changed."
    sleep 5
}

#Change profile picture f(x)
#Ex. changeProfilePicture username /path/to/image.png
function changeProfilePicture() {
    FILE="$(readlink -f "$2")"
    fileName="${FILE##*/}" # baseName + fileExtension

    echo "Checking if 'imagemagick' is installed ..."
    if ! command brew ls --versions imagemagick >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Installing 'imagemagick' ..."
        brew install imagemagick -y
        echo "'Imagemagick' has been installed."
        sleep 5
    else
        echo "'Imagemagick' has already been installed."
        sleep 5
    fi

    echo "Changing profile picture to: '$fileName' ..."
    sudo mkdir -p '/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/'"$1"
    sudo convert "$2" -set filename:f '/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/'"$1/%t" -resize 96x96 '%[filename:f].png'
    echo "Profile picture has been changed."
    sleep 5
}
```

Comment: Seems like apt-get should be efficient enough to do nothing it it's already installed, so if you don;t want to use a more mature solution like configuration management, I suppose simply trying to apt-get all the packages in one line would be more efficient than what you're doing, since each "which" command is going to cause a process overhead, and apt-get uses a locally cached database which should be quick enough to search.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Playing devil's advocate the `apt-get update` might not be desirable to run unless you already knew you were probably going to install a package.

Comment: Another thing though would be the line about how the ppa is being added. A utility not existing doesn't mean that the repo that provides it doesn't already exist. I don't know enough about debian to know if that's a bug but it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the user to manually use `gnome-tweak-tool`, you can set the gtk and window-manager themes and the icon-theme in your script with `gsettings`.  e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Numix
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Numix
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme Numix-Circle
```

BTW, unless `numix-gtk-theme` and `numix-icon-theme-circle` are executables somewhere in the PATH directories, running `which` on them will not do what you want.

Check for the existence of a specific file or directory, instead.  e.g.

```
if [ ! -d /usr/share/themes/Numix ] ; then ... fi
```

I don't have the Numix theme installed, so I don't know if that's the right directory - use `dpkg -L numix-gtk-theme` and `dpkg -L numix-icon-theme-circle` to find out the correct directories to search for.

Alternatively, don't bother checking to see if the packages are already installed.  Just run:

```
apt-get -y install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme-circle gnome-tweak-tool
```

(optionally redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null)

If the latest version of those packages is already installed, `apt-get` will do nothing.  Otherwise, it will install or upgrade them.

Finally, use `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:numix/ppa` so that it doesn't prompt the user.  If the repository has already been added, no harm done - it will comment out previous entries in the `/etc/sources.list.d/numix-ubuntu-ppa-yakkety.list` file and add the ppa to the start of the file.

Comment: Wow thank you for your in depth response! I am still new to bash so I appreciate it!